# AWS DOCS throwing 403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied docs.aws.amazon.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I was trying to access https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html and a few more links of aws docs which are usually available for free and without any account.

But unfortunately, it was not loading for me and throwing this error.

> 403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied. Request blocked. We
> can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time.
> There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again
> later, or contact the app or website owner. If you provide content to
> customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and
> help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
>
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID:
> 2_MUN1cR-TsGw8oDL5w38oxzdZEAPWhGc3-LVF1XVUmiIlypRn6fig==

I tried to load the same link in incognito mode which works. But not in the current browser. I wanted to open links to docs.aws.amazon.com

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same.

Comment: @TheAshwaniK yes please check the first answer I provided here below. If that works for you don’t forget to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to clear the

- Cookies
- Local Storage
- Session Storage

Then do hard refresh <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> **or** <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Most probably I was opening multiple tabs and selected multiple regions in those multiple tabs.